# A Sufficient condition for a curve being perpendicular to a constant vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

I solved this problem on my own, months ago, but the solution seems to me completely forgotten, a little help on it would be appreciated:

Suppose $\alpha= \alpha(t)$ on an interval $I$ is a smooth (of class C$^1$) parametric representation of the curve $C$, and for any $t \in I$ we have $\space\space\frac{d}{dt}\alpha(t).v=0$, where $v$ is a constant vector, furthermore $\alpha(0)$ is perpendicular to $v$.
Then $\forall t\in I: \space \alpha(t).v=0$.

Comment: So you want to prove $a(t)\cdot v\equiv 0$ on $I$? Isn't it part of the given information though?

Comment: Oops, my mistake, I'm editing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the ambient space is $\Bbb R^n$. Then $\alpha'(t)$ always lives in $\text{ker} \,v$, a subspace orthogonal to $v$. This suggests we use an orthogonal transformation $\rho$ to change coordinates, so that $\rho w$ is in the same direction as $e_n$ and $\rho\alpha'(t)$ lives in the span of $e_1,\cdots,e_{n-1}$, denoted $V$. We now only have to show $\rho\alpha(t)$ lives in $V+h$ for some $h\in\Bbb R^n$. Denote $\beta:=\rho\alpha$ then $\beta'=\rho\alpha'$. We only look at the $n$-th componenent of $\beta$ now. I assume by $I$ you mean $[0,1]$. So let $h:=\beta(0)$, we claim $\beta(I)\subset h+V$: otherwise suppose $\exists t_0$ s.t. $\beta^n(t_0)-\beta^n(0)\ne 0$. However, by the fundamental theorem of calculus applied to $\beta^n$ we know that
$$\beta^n(t_0)-\beta^n(0)=\int_{[0,t_0]}(\beta^n)'(t)\mathrm dt=\int 0 = 0.$$

Comment: Vectors also have kernels? I didn't know that.

Comment: @AshkanRanjbar ok I should have clarified. By this I mean the set $\{x\mid x\cdot w=0\}$ i.e. If you treat $w$ as a linear operator $x\mapsto w\cdot x$.

Comment: and what is $w$? just any arbitrary vector orthogonal to $v$?

Comment: @AshkanRanjbar $w$ is $v$. Sorry.

Comment: I forgot my own solution back then, but I'm sure it was way different than yours, and pretty much simpler than this, and I must admit that it's very difficult for me to get the point you're trying to make, however your solution somehow hints me to use mean value theorem for integrals (and of course componentwise), but I could not figure it out how to use it, meanwhile, could you please if possible send me another simpler solution? and let your current solution be justified by other experts in the forum.

Comment: What specifically do you not understand in my answer? Feel free to ask and I'm glad to clarify. I'm going to leave this answer to the judgement of other experts. But I'm not going to post another answer.

Comment: You're very kind, thank you. Hmmm deep down I always had trouble understanding change of basis in linear algebra, yours is even more strange than the ones I fairly recall (mine were $P^T A P$ like), also why would you want to show $\rho\alpha(t) $ lives in $V+h$ since, that $h$ causes some trouble for me(isn't it the same as the integral constant?) and finally why we left to check the n-th component of $\beta$?

Comment: @AshkanRanjbar 1). Change of coordinates is not essential, but it can simplify our analysis. The idea is, originally, since $v$ is kinda arbitrary, $\text{ker}\,v$ may be a *tilted* subspace, which makes it troublesome to express orthodogonal "component" in coordinate form. But after a coordinate change we basically tilt the space back to the upright position (span of $e_i,i=1,\cdots,n-1$). An orthogonal transformation is a zero-preserving rigid body motion, so however the subspaces is originally tilted, we are always guaranteed to find an orthogonal transformation to set it back "upright".

Comment: @AshkanRanjbar 2). $V+h$ is the vector sum, which you can simply interpret as an affine space parallel to $V$. Formally it is $\{x+h\mid x\in V\}$. 3). Because as I said in the last comment, after the "tilt" i.e. the orthogonal transformation, $v$ now becomes $\rho v$, which is in the same direction as $e_n$ and the subspace $\alpha'$ originally lives in is now set in an "upright" position i.e. the "horizontal plane". We want to show $\beta$ is always orthogonal to $\rho v$, or equivalently is always confined to an affine space parallel to the horizontal plane $V$, so we only have to show its.

Comment: @AshkanRanjbar ... $n$-th component stays constant. If you want to visualise, think about $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Thx, now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ \; t_0 \in \mathrm{dom(\alpha)} $ the FTC for vector valued functions implies
$$\require{cancel}\alpha(t_0 ) -\alpha(0) = \int_{0}^{t_0} \dot\alpha(v)dv\qquad(1)$$
Now apply dot product upon (1) and $v$ will result (using $<,>$ as the dot operator)
$$<v,\alpha(t_0)> -\cancelto{0}{<v,\alpha(0)>}=<v,\int_{0}^{t_0}\dot \alpha(u)du>$$
But
$$<v,\int_{0}^{t_0}\dot \alpha(u)du>=\int_{0}^{t_0}<v,\dot \alpha(u)>du$$ Using our hypothesis and the fact that $t_0$ was taken arbitrarily it follows $$\forall t\in\mathrm{dom}(\alpha) \quad<\alpha(t),v>=0$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: Nice this argument is certainly cleaner than mine.